# Xorg X server tries to delete ubuntu-desktop, help!

Tags: drivers, xorg, eeepc

I have recently installed ubuntu 12.04 on my Asus eeePC cx1015. Video files, however are stuttering, and I figured the drivers are not installed.

I went to synaptic, and chose to install the "cedarview-graphics-driver", but it failed and told me:

```
The following packages have unersolveable dependencies. 
Make sure that all required repositories are added and enabled in 
the preferences.

cedarview-graphics-drivers:
 Depends:xserver-xorg-core (>=2:1.10.99.901)
 Depends:xorg-video-abi-11
```

I tried to install xserver-xorg-core but then it told me I had to remove a few packages. Including one package called **ubuntu-desktop**, which is crazy.

Can anyone help me please? I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, after much digging, I eventually solved this.

it turns out that from version 12.04.02 onward Ubuntu uses newer xserver-xorg versions, which the installation for the graphics driver have not been updated to support.

The solution is to install Ubuntu **12.04.01** (from [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/)) and everything went smooth from there.